# Tomcat doesn't return image resources

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

I'm using eclipse and run my jsp/servlet using tomcat6 from eclipse. My servlet creates for me an image that i store in to a directory in my webapps. But when i try to access to this image from my JSP it returns me that the resource is not available.

What's the problem?

Servlet store image in "myapp/images/saved.png"

[image]

Comment: Need to show us some code and the layout of your war.

Comment: @Woot4Moo what code you need?

Comment: The servlet that serves up the code, jsp/html something along those lines so we can see how the page is failing to serve the content.

Comment: the problem is that even if the image is stored in the rigth position, if i try to access to localhost:8080/myapp/images/saved.png it gives me error

Comment: I dont think the image is where you think it is.  does /myapp/images return anything?

Comment: no, it give me the same error. But the servlet store it here. It's a problem in displaying it.

Comment: @Woot4Moo The requested resource (/myapp/images/saved.png) is not available. but the image is in the directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `images` directory into the `WebContent` directory. That will make it work.

Comment: it works now!!! Thanks a lot. I don't know why all the negative rates for my question. You centered how to solve my problem. Thanks again!!!