# render new image without refresh project and restart tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tomcat doesn’t return image resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12770989/tomcat-doesnt-return-image-resources)

I have this java code, that stores a new image in /images directory

```
BufferedImage new_image = ImageIO.read(image);

File outputfile = new File("/prova/WebContent/images/image.png");
ImageIO.write(new_image, "png", outputfile);

out.println("<body>" +
            "<img src=\"/prova/images/image.png\">" +
            "</body>");
```

but I have one problem. After that i need to display my image in the resulting JSP. But it doesn't return me the image. Only if i refresh my project in eclipse it gives me the image.

Any idea to resolve automatically?

Comment: *"Only if i refresh my project in eclipse it gives me the image."*  Does Eclipse use an internal browser for this?  It is probably just caching the original image.  But why is this web app. producing different images with the same name anyway?  If each one had a time-stamp as part of the file name (or the parameters used to generate it) the file names would become unique and the problem would disappear.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson my webapp generates dinamically images, so i need to solve this problem. No eclipse doesn't use its own browser. This is an example code, in my servlet i have a variable instead of "image.png"

Comment: *"my webapp generates dinamically images.."*  That leads me back to  (a little louder, this time) ***"If each one had a time-stamp as part of the file name (or the parameters used to generate it) the file names would become unique and the problem would disappear."***

Comment: No, because if i try to show this image it returns me "not available resource" error :)